# Angular 6 no me carga Jquery al navegar entre vistas

Tags: jquery, angular, chart.js

estoy implementando un template de un  dashboard que tiene como depencia jQuery, chart js etc. 
Todo me iba bien hasta la hora de implementar las rutas ya que ahora cuando navego por ellas me sale el error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined 
Lo curioso es que si refresco manualmente (F5) funciona perfectamente pero el momento vuelo a navegar por las rutas vuelve a aparecer el mensaje y a no cargarse me los chart ni las tablas dinámicas

He probado definiendo la ruta del Jquery en package.json pero nada

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "auto-vision": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/auto-vision",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"

              
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "auto-vision:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "auto-vision:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "auto-vision:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"

            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "auto-vision-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "auto-vision:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "auto-vision:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "auto-vision"
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="loading" lang="en" data-textdirection="ltr">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/app-assets/css/vendors.css">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
  <meta name="description" content="Sitio web donde monitorizar todos los datos a tiempo real de sus maquinas.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="administrador, autovision, monitorizacion">
  <meta name="Alvaro Ramirez Palazon" content="AutoVision">
  <title>Panel  
  </title>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../../assets/app-assets/images/ico/apple-icon-120.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../../assets/app-assets/images/ico/favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Quicksand:300,400,500,700"
  rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/fonts/line-awesome/1.1/css/line-awesome.min.css"
  
  rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- BEGIN VENDOR CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/app-assets/css/vendors.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/app-assets/vendors/css/tables/datatable/datatables.min.css">
  <!-- END VENDOR CSS-->
  <!-- BEGIN MODERN CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/app-assets/css/app.css">
  <!-- END MODERN CSS-->
  <!-- BEGIN Page Level CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/app-assets/css/core/menu/menu-types/horizontal-menu.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/app-assets/css/core/colors/palette-gradient.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/app-assets/vendors/css/charts/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css">

 

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/app-assets/fonts/simple-line-icons/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/app-assets/css/core/colors/palette-gradient.css">
  <!-- END Page Level CSS-->
  <!-- BEGIN Custom CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/css/style.css">
  <!-- END Custom CSS-->



</head>
<body class="horizontal-layout horizontal-menu 2-columns   menu-expanded" data-open="hover"
data-menu="horizontal-menu" data-col="2-columns">



<app-root></app-root>
     
<!-- BEGIN VENDOR JS-->
<!--<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->

<script src="../../assets/app-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- BEGIN VENDOR JS-->
 <!-- BEGIN PAGE VENDOR JS-->

 


 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/app-assets/vendors/js/ui/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/app-assets/vendors/js/charts/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../../assets/app-assets/vendors/js/charts/chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../assets/app-assets/vendors/js/charts/raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/js/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>

 <script src="../../assets/app-assets/vendors/js/charts/jvector/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../assets/app-assets/vendors/js/charts/jvector/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../assets/app-assets/data/jvector/visitor-data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../assets/app-assets/vendors/js/tables/datatable/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/app-assets/vendors/css/cryptocoins/cryptocoins.css">


 <!-- END PAGE VENDOR JS-->
 <!-- BEGIN MODERN JS-->
 <script src="../../assets/app-assets/js/core/app-menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../assets/app-assets/js/core/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../assets/app-assets/js/scripts/customizer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- END MODERN JS-->
 <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL JS-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/app-assets/js/scripts/ui/breadcrumbs-with-stats.js"></script>
 <script src="../../assets/app-assets/js/scripts/pages/dashboard-sales.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="../../assets/app-assets/js/scripts/tables/datatables/datatable-basic.js"
  type="text/javascript"></script>

  


 <!-- END PAGE LEVEL JS-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu index.html tiene un aspecto inusual, pero bueno, iniciaría intentando incluir esta biblioteca como una dependencia a tu proyecto.

1. Instala la dependencia

> npm install jquery --save

2. Incluya la ruta de tu dependencia en tu ./angular-cli.json

> "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"]

3. Llamar jQuery en tu componente

> import * as $ from 'jquery';

Con esto ya deberias poder utilizar jQuery dentro de tu componente sin problemas

Comment: Buenas noches Jonathan muchas gracias por la respuesta pero no me funciona, el problema es que cuando ejecuto el componente donde se encuentra los chart o datatable se bloquea ya que intenta acceder al archivo <script src="../../assets/app-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> (situado en el index.html) que dentro de este no encuentra la variable Jquery. Me comentas que el archivo index.html tiene un formato inusual, si tienes algún consejo para mi te lo agradecería. Muchas gracias por todo
Un saludo

Comment: Hola Alvaro, creo que lo que pasa es que aun no tienes claro como se deben de insertar las dependencias en Angular.
En el desarrollo web tradicional (sin usar framework) se incrustan por medio de una etiqueta `<script>` justo antes de `</body>`, de la misma forma como lo estas asiendo actualmente, pero en Angular al igual que en cualquier otro framework esto se debe realizar por medio de un gestor de paquetes como npm o yarn, tal como se lo indique arriba. En estos gestores de paquetes existen bibliotecas preparadas para implementar charts y datatables en Angular.

Comment: No es aconsejable utilizar jQuery en un framework. Para eso existen bibliotecas listas para implementar lo que necesites sin la necesidad de este

Comment: Muchimas gracias por la repuesta lo haré de nuevo usando los paquetes de npm para mejorar mi aprendizaje